# Add a reference to assembly

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms, assembly-references, xlabs

I am developing a Cross Platform app with Xamarin.Forms PCL and I want to add Xlabs to my project.

I have read how to implement it [here](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki).

I found the following problem. When I try to add this code to "App.cs" in my WinPhone 8.1 project:

```
var app = new XFormsAppWP();
app.Init(this);
```

on "**Init**" (app.**Init**(this)) I had this problem:

```
The type 'Application' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. 
You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'
```

I have a "Quick Fix" option -> Add a reference to assembly `System.Windows, Version=2.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e`, but when I try to click on it, nothing happens.

In "Reference Manager" (WinPhone project -> Right click -> Add reference) I can't add this reference because I can't found it.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 pro, my project is targeting .NET 4.5 (I tried also with 4.5.2 but I had the same problem).

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you added the XLabs.Forms package to your projects (PCL and WP)?